# How to set togglebutton in a Service?

Tags: android, android-service

Hi guys i have a Activity and into this i run Service A and into Service A run Service B

Activity > Service A > Service B

Service B has a method called "MyMethod()". I want set in Service B Togglebutton in NOT CHECKED.
I have tried to use getSharedPreference in Service B but i don't know how update the status of the togglebutton in Activity: This is My Activity:

```
 final ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);

    btn.setChecked(
            getSharedPreferences("btn", MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getBoolean("state", false)
    );

    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

//for RunAsyncTask
    final Intent intentAsyncTask = new Intent(DettagliVolo.this, RunAsyncTask.class);

    pIntentAsyncTask = PendingIntent.getService(DettagliVolo.this, 0, intentAsyncTask, 0);
 btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10 * 1000, pIntentAsyncTask);
                } else {
                    alarm.cancel(pIntentAsyncTask);
                    stopService(intentAsyncTask);
                }
                getSharedPreferences("btn", MODE_PRIVATE)
                        .edit().putBoolean("state", isChecked)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

Sorry for my english
In Service B:

```
 @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int idArranque) {
         if(a) i want set togglebutton FALSE;
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can add your Activity as SharedPreferencesListener (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) Although it's used mainly with xml preferences, it can help. For code sample see http://envyandroid.com/archives/1104/android-detect-preference-changes
2. send intent from service to activity with defined broadcast receiver. Or put Messenger to activity's intent to service extra. This messenger should be bound to Handler in the activity. E.g. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#servicecommunication_handler, or http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger

Comment: what's the simple and fast solution?

Comment: first one is simpler and implements in a minute - just as @Olayinka suggested. second one gives you much more control over your app's inner communication.

Answer (score 1):

When do you see the change in toggle button? On the launch of activity, right?

Get the `SharedPreferences` in `Service` B and update the `state`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("btn", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("state", false).commit();
```

Now, on launch of the `Activity`, set the toggle button based on value of `SharedPreferences`.